# Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<page>[^/]+)$']

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to code wiki plagia. But I got this unexpected error: Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P[^/]+)$']. So there is the page of the Python Function who redirect it.

```html
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<form method=POST action="{% url 'edit' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>The Title Of Your Wiki Page</label>
    <input type="text" name="Title" value="None">
    <label>The Content Of Your Wiki Page</label>
    <input type="text" name="Content" value="None">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Your Wiki Page" value="None">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

And there is my Python Function :

```
def edit(request):
    print(page)
    return render(request,"encyclopedia/edit.html")
```

The path fuction in urls.py:

```
path("edit/<str:page>", views.edit, name="edit")
```

Th wiki.html page who redirect to the edit function:

{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

```
{% block body %}

{{content|safe}}
<form action="/edit/{{name}}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you need to share code of the view which renders the html code given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your code

1. You need to provide an argument to the `edit`function i.e.`page` since the url `path("edit/<str:page>", views.edit, name="edit")`  is passing a parameter `<str:page>` to the function

   ```
   def edit(request, page):
       print(page)
       return render(request,"encyclopedia/edit.html")
   ```
2. You need to provide argument to the URL `{% url 'edit' %}` in the template

   `{% url 'edit' argument %}`